# Open Spree::User class and add functions without losing existing functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, metaprogramming, spree

I'd like to add the `vendor?` method to the `Spree::User` class.

`Spree::User` is defined in the solidus gem that my Rails app uses. I don't want to touch this code but rather open the class and append my methods to it in the main Rails app.

E.g: RAILS_ROOT/app/models/spree/user.rb

```
module Spree
  class User < Spree::Base

    include Spree::UserMethods

    def vendor?
      self.role_users.any? { |ru| ru.role.name == 'vendor' }
    end

  end    
end
```

This however does not include methods like `admin?` that were present before I created my patch.

Is there a way I can extend the existing class without manually copying all of it's methods manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file under `config/initializers` directory:

```
# config/initializers/spree_user.rb

Spree::User.class_eval do
  def vendor?
    self.role_users.any? { |ru| ru.role.name == 'vendor' }
  end
end
```

It will just add your single method to the existing class.

Comment: Nice, that was it! :-D